# htaccess redirect affiliate link

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Using

```
RewriteRule ^affiliates/(.+)$ /businessdirectory [L,R=301]
```

does not work. The user is left at the home page (index.php).

From this link :

- /affiliates/aff_tools/davidc/tool/email_ads/3

the visitor is "supposed" to be redirected to :

- /properties/detail/real-estate-agencies-example-2

The affiliate software allows the redirect added within the software. So, when the user hits the .../3 link, they arrive at the ...example-2 page of the site.

What is happening is that the user is sent to the home page. They are not redirected to the updated directory, and certainly are not redirected to the ...example-2 as expected.

If the user clicks on the "new" link :

- /business/directory/aff_tools/davidc/tool/email_ads/3

then the user is redirected properly and lands on the ...example-2 page as intended.
So, why is the redirect in htaccess not working?

Answer (score 0):

It took a LOT of testing and searching, but here is the answer.

In the original folder - `/affiliates/` - create an `.htaccess` file. For "each" link that needs to be redirected, follow this example:

```bash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/affiliates/aff_tools/username/tool/email_ads/3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.whateverdomain.com/businessdirectory/aff_tools/username/tool/email_ads/3/ [R=301,L]
```

I hope this will help others.